# Windows 10 - Sound works in test but stopped working everywhere else

Tags: windows-10, audio, speakers

This happened out of the blue yesterday. If I test in:

- speaker properties > advanced > Test, or
- Enhancements > Preview

it actually works, but nowhere else was I able to play the sound.

**Troubleshooting**

1. Setting the speakers to default (already set)
2. Updating the drive
3. Virus scan
4. being able to play sounds with a Bluetooth device but **not when plugging a headset in the headphone jack**
5. Uninstalled recently installed software (probably irrelevant: MongoDB)

Edit: A few more things I had tried but forgot to mention:

6. Windows troubleshooter didn't help
7. turned off enhancements

Answer (score 2):

Try these steps, i had same issues and restarting audio services helped me

If you still have problems, try to restart your audio services:

1. Type and select “Services” in the search box of the taskbar.

2.Right click on “Windows Audio” and select “Restart”. Do the same with the services “Windows Audio Endpoint Builder” and “Remote Procedure Call “RPC”.

There are couple of more methods, check [windows sound problems](https://windowsmaximizer.com/tutorials/windows-10-sound-problems/) here

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, that did not work. I also went through the steps one by one, none worked. This is so puzzling to me because when I "test" the sound it works.

Answer (score 1):

Run the Windows audio troubleshooter:

- Run `Troubleshooting` from the Start menu
- Click on `Troubleshoot audio playback`
- Follow the prompts
- Reboot.

Comment: thank you, already have done that, it suggested setting the audio device as default and turning off enhancements, both of which were already done.

Comment: A pity - this once fixed such a problem for me. What model is the audio device?

Comment: Sorry I have just seen this. I do still have this issue. The device in the device manager says High Definition Audio Device. Don't know if there's another way to know what model I have.

Comment: Device Manager > right-click > Properties > Details > Hardware IDs, search the string on internet.